# Can the code in an excel vba module become corrupted?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel 2010. Can an ordinary module (not userform, class) become corrupted somehow? I can open my project, even run code, but for one particular module, can't edit, can't even delete it without Excel crashing. ?It's just code, isn't it?

Specific question: Is this a known problem with a known cause and/or solution? While I find plenty of info about corrupted worksheets etc. on the web, I don't find much about this situation. Is there somewhere I can look? Is there a remedy?

Comment: Yes, any part of an Excel file can get corrupted.  First thing I would try, create a new excel file and copy all your data and VBA over to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend the VBA Code Cleaner from AppsPro.  What the CodeCleaner does is export all the modules to a folder and then re-export.   So actually, if for some reason you cannot install Code Cleaner (because of corporate policy or something) then you can do this manually by right clicking on the module and take the relevant menu item.

http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm

Comment: Thanks, that proved useful. Running the code cleaner on that sheet reduced its size a good deal, and it now ran. I think a mis-shaped data validation routine on the sheet may have been causing the problem. Apparently data validation can do that, I've seen elsewhere.

Comment: Code Cleaner doesn't support 64-bit versions.  However another utility [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66862471/2662901) called [VBA Code Decompiler](https://orlandomvp.org/VBADecompilerMore.asp) appears to have been updated and does.