# How to load .NET Framework in Excel

Tags: .net, excel, vba

I've been successfully using .NET Framework classes in my VBA code within Excel for some time. Specifically, I create `System.Text.StringBuilder` object like this:

```vb
Set sBuilder = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
```

Until February 2024, whenever I launched Excel, it seemed to pre-load the .NET Framework automatically, and my macros ran without any issues. However, recently I've noticed a change in this behaviour:

When I start Excel and run my VBA, I receive automation errors. Interestingly, if I open PowerQuery first (which seems to load the .NET Framework), subsequent execution of the same macros works fine, just like before. This leads me to believe that the root cause of the issue is the .NET Framework not being pre-loaded when Excel starts.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to ensure that the .NET Framework is pre-loaded when Excel starts, either via VBA or some Excel settings?
2. Has there been a recent update or change in Excel's behaviour regarding .NET Framework loading that I might not be aware of?
   Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve these automation errors would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could add a reference to mscorlib.tlb v2.4 to use the .Net Framework classes. If using Rubberduck fairly easy to add otherwise will have to find it's location  eg. Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb  Currently slowly doing a project [VBA-DotNetLib](https://github.com/MarkJohnstoneGitHub/VBA-DotNetLib/) wrapping various .Net Frameworkclasses instead of using mscorlib as provides intellisense for classes and factory methods that aren't available. It's a work in progress.  Mainly started for DateTime and TimeZoneInfo related classes also have wrappeed StringBuilder.

Comment: Regarding Power Query in Excel for Windows uses the .NET framework, but it requires version 4.7.2 or later.  For why getting automation errors now when didn't have it before maybe registry changes have been made.  Have you tried reinstalling the .Net Framework? A quick test using late binding as per  your example not having any issues in Ms-Access.

Comment: Adding reference to mscorlib did not help.

Comment: Did you use early binding and mscorlib.tlb 2.4 eg. Dim sb As mscorlib.StringBuilder: Set sb = New mscorlib.StringBuilder that should work.  I have a quick example in a Ms-Excel for displaying StringBuilder members.  [VBADotNetLib.xlsm](https://github.com/MarkJohnstoneGitHub/VBA-DotNetLib/blob/main/VBA/Ms-Excel/VBADotNetLib.xlsm) the TestStringBuilder.bas an early and late binding version.  See DisplayStringBuilderMembers, DisplayStringBuilderMembersV2.  Also have wrapped the .Net StringBuilder thou required the DotNetLib.tlb and register it to use.

Comment: As to why getting issues if .Net Framework 4.7.2 or later is installed.  Hmm automation errors so not Runtime Error  '429' ActiveX component can't create an object so creating the  object is fine?  Occurs when accessing a member of  StringBuilder?  What is the code causing the  Automation error? i.e. Are you getting Error '430' Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface

Comment: Any particular reason why using late binding? Preferable use early binding. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients

Comment: [good_way_to_find_the_progid_for_a_library](https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/bw0ipm/good_way_to_find_the_progid_for_a_library/) Code there might help you, listing all progId etd from the registry to help troubleshoot.  Incase it's a registry issue.

Comment: Dim sb As mscorlib.StringBuilder: Set sb = New mscorlib.StringBuilder also throws "Automation error". When I use late-binding aka Dim sb As Object: Set sb = CreateObject("mscorlib.StringBuilder") I get "ActiveX component can't create object" error. I have reference to mscorlib.dll

Comment: So early and late binding don't work. Instincts are hinting it's likely a registry issue. To use any type library it must be registered correctly. Did you get the listCOMClasses Sub working from the reddit link above and search the results for StringBuilder? That should find an entry. Possible files moved or missing the Prog Id is linked to.  Fixing any registry issues might require unregistering the type library and reregister.  A reinstall of .Net Framework should fix it.

Comment: Apart from that google automation error. Eg. [Run-time error '2147319767 (80028029) - Automation error - Invalid forward reference, or reference to uncompiled type](https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/vnnkh9/runtime_error_2147319767_80028029_automation/)

Comment: [recovery-from-excel-vba-corruption-and-automation-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66862470/recovery-from-excel-vba-corruption-and-automation-errors)